# Add day(s) in a date in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have textbox displaying date and have a button. the function in button is to add 7 days and display in textbox. my code:

```
 function onNext() {    
    var startdate = document.getElementById('date').value;
    var addday = new Date(startdate);
    var dd = addday.getDate() + 7;
    var mm = addday.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = addday.getFullYear();
    var displaydate = y + '/' + mm + '/' + dd;
    document.getElementById('date').value = displaydate ;
}
```

The issue how to add a day to go to the next month.

Example the date in Textbox is 2014/08/25 when I click the button the date will be 2014/09/01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add 7 days to your date, date already handles change of month/year:

```
 function onNext() {    
    var startdate = document.getElementById('date').value;
    var addday = new Date(startdate);
    addday.setDate(addday.getDate() + 7);
    var dd = addday.getDate() + 7;
    var mm = addday.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = addday.getFullYear();
    var displaydate = y + '/' + mm + '/' + dd;
    document.getElementById('date').value = displaydate ;
}
```

Comment: thanks! this line of code works fine "addday.setDate(addday.getDate() + 7);"

Answer (score 0):

If you just do this

```
 var dd = addday.getDate() + 7;
 var mm = addday.getMonth() + 1;
 var y = addday.getFullYear();
```

that means if date is 21.12.2014 the output will be 28.13.2014

```
function onNext() {    
    var startdate = document.getElementById('date').value;
    var d2 = new Date(startdate);

    d2.setMonth(d2.getMonth()+1);
    d2.setDate(1); // you can set here whatever date you want
    document.getElementById('date').value = d2.getFullYear() + '/' + d2.getMonth() + '/' + d2. getDate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
 function updateAb(s){//format dd/mm/yyyy chnage according to your need
        var dmy = s.split("/");   

        var joindate = new Date(
            parseInt(dmy[2], 10),
            parseInt(dmy[1], 10) - 1,
            parseInt(dmy[0], 10)
        );
        var data_days=7;

        joindate.setDate(joindate.getDate() + data_days); 
        var cc=("0" + joindate.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" +("0" + (joindate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" +joindate.getFullYear();
        document.getElementById("datepickerdisabled1").value=cc;
    }
```